# Is there any programming practice website for beginners in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am doing an online course on Reinforcement Learning from university of Alberta. 
It focus too much on theory. I am engineering and I am interested towards applying RL to my applications directly.

My question is, is there any website which has sample programmers for beginners. Small sample programs. 
I have seen several websites for other machine learning topics such as CNN/RNN etc. But the resources for RL are either limited, or I couldn't find them

Comment: The course you are referring to does have programming assignments for most of the studied concepts/algorithms. Did you check those?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning or a course where they teach RL with a focus on the implementation part too? Do the answers to [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18798/2444) answer your question? If yes, feel free to upvote them (including the question), then I will close this question a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since you are a beginner, I strongly recommend you start reading [Sutton's book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf). It is a really great book.

Then, some tutorials:

[udemy rl](https://www.udemy.com/course/machine-learning-beginner-reinforcement-learning-in-python/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DataScience_v.PROF_la.EN_cc.ROW_ti.5336&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_85469003954_._ad_437497334835_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-774930036449_._li_9067687_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=CjwKCAjw8df2BRA3EiwAvfZWaFozTSdALFp3qg_IFF5R_4PL6SGbeM5W_WGtGy5teJ5MW1Lef6dwBBoCqU0QAvD_BwE)

[udemy deep rl](https://www.udemy.com/course/deep-reinforcement-learning/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DeepLearning_v.PROF_la.EN_cc.ROW_ti.5374&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_85479010714_._ad_437497336740_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-774930039529_._li_9067687_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=CjwKCAjw8df2BRA3EiwAvfZWaFHx42hKDJfUvGf_QPU7Bsub7wX1zGP6M8vz8maEP5EMAgEbu76rSRoCCiwQAvD_BwE)

[rl-with-tensorflow](https://github.com/MorvanZhou/Reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow)

[learndatasci](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/reinforcement-q-learning-scratch-python-openai-gym/)

[stackabuse](https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-reinforcement-learning-with-python/)